# Mouseover issue and windows opening behind other windows - Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, firefox, adobe-photoshop

I have decided to close my original post and move this question here as it seems more fitting on super user for multiple reasons.

Recently when I leave my PC on for a few days I get this strange glitch that makes my preview windows, hover messages, and other items not work, as well as when I open a program it opens behind everything else.

For someone who is programming a lot I bet you can understand how this can be troublesome. The worst part is it only happens when the PC has been on for a few days, a restart of the system will fix the issues but it only lasts a few days and then goes back to the same problem.

Here is some imagery to show you the problem as it's hard to explain properly:

- https://i.gyazo.com/9530787c5381f2d538b0609384399f4c.gif
- https://i.gyazo.com/ecf5b425cdc90376f06a1cac9dc3c538.gif
- https://i.gyazo.com/fa518a7e059c514839c42892445106e3.gif
- https://i.gyazo.com/b6d93d65951c144d43cebe6813e831ba.gif

> The second image flashes a lot faster then you can see in the GIF because the frame rate
>   isn't capturing it exactly, refer to the third image for a better understanding.

As you can see it works for mouse over on my HTML page in Firefox (sometimes this fails too) and on android studio it won't let me see what the error is because the popup vanishes so fast. This is not limited to Android Studio either, hovering the icons in the task bar where you get the popup window to show you a preview will flash really fast on and off and other programs fail with similar glitches. Also, in Photoshop CS6 hovering over drop-downs or left clicking buttons that make drop menus doesn't work, they show up and then vanish really quickly. Right click seems to work on those but not left click or hover (like changing layer transparency).

When it gets in this mode, opening an app from start menu for example, will cause the new app to open behind all the other windows. If I reset the PC then these issues are fixed temporarily until it's been on for a few days.

Anyone have any ideas? I already checked and made sure my `ForegroundFlashCount` was set to `3` (it had been at 7 for some reason) in the registry and that my `CursorBlinkRate` was at `500` (had also been at set higher at 530) as suggested for defaults on Microsoft's website. I am at a loss here and its annoying.

Comment: This can be many things. I would start with updating everying. All drivers, windows update, etc. Also, check for malware.

Comment: @LPChip thanks for the reply. It's not Malware, system has been checked constantly and is my database machine so it's under 24/7 supervision. All the latest drivers are installed and every update has been installed released as of this date. It only happens when the PC runs for a few days and Microsoft support team was no help to us either.

Comment: I know it's not the answer you want but, after you update drivers and try different hardware (different mouse/keyboard etc) then you may have to consider nuking the machine :S

Comment: I've observed this behavior on Firefox and Chrome from time to time. Usually when the programs have been open for a while (several days or at least overnight) and the computer has not been restarted recently. I've generally assumed it was a faulty/poor interaction between Explorer/DWM and the browser. What sort of database is this machine hosting?

Comment: MySQL 5 database.